# Is there any way to know who downvoted an answer and why they did so?

Tags: support, downvotes

Is there any way to know who downvoted an answer and why they did so? I'm asking this just because many users downvote without leaving any comment. So we don't know why our answer gets downvoted so that we try to improve it.

Comment: No, there isn't. Votes are anonymous.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12984/165773

Answer (score 30):

No, there isn't.

You could post a comment asking who downvoted, although the success rate of this isn't particularly high (especially if the post is old, or an answer to an old question. If you do choose this route, do try to be as friendly as possible - it's very unlikely that someone will comment if they suspect you're going to downvote them for revenge.

In some cases, you could post on Meta, although I'd say this is more for downvotes on questions (and perhaps answers with an extreme number of downvotes) - the correctness / usefulness of answers tend to require some domain knowledge, which shouldn't be expected to exist on Meta.

Answer (score 15):

No. There is not. You could ask in a comment for clarification, and most of the time someone will give the reason most people downvoted you.

Also, usually the 'How to Ask' gives a guideline how to ask good questions. When your question doesn't comply to those rules people tend to downvote.