# See how others reviewed a post in late answer queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage, late-answers

Looking back at my reviews I sometimes wonder how others reviewed the item I reviewed. To check if my judging of quality is still apropriate, and in line with community consensus. In the Triage queue you can see what opinions others have, and what the final say on that post was.

For example on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18228815 one person voted "Looks OK", myself and 1 other person voted "Unsalvagable" and two others voted "Requires Editing"

When I look back at a post I reviewed in the late answer queue I would be interested to see the same sort of overview. For example on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18228567. But here I only see that I "Reviewed" this post.

Now is it simply that this post in the Late Answer queue only required one review, being mine, and therefore there is nothing more to display, which I doubt tbh. Or is there some other reason for not showing the community concensus on such a review?

**Edit:**
This question is not a duplicate of the question brought forward by gnat as I am not interested in seeing who voted what on an answer.

Comment: There's only one reviewer per review for late answers so there's no community concensus to speak of. The closest you'll get is checking if the flags you've raised during reviews are marked helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to know who downvoted an answer and why they did so?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252098/is-there-any-way-to-know-who-downvoted-an-answer-and-why-they-did-so)

Comment: since up/down voting (which counts as an action for LA/FP reviews) is anonymous by design exposing it in reviews is not feasible

Comment: @gnat that late-answer review doesn't have any votes so I'm not sure how that duplicate applies. We first need to establish why it got kicked from the review queue

Comment: You might want to check if my script is useful for you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/158100

Comment: @rene [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47769988/timeline) suggests that this may be impacted by outcome of [FP review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18228369)

Comment: @gnat yeah, and I only now read the first comment. So that probably explains all of this. Still the dupe is not correct  imo.

Comment: @gnat, I fail to see how that is a dupe. But reading ivarni's comment gave me the answer I sought.

Comment: @ivarni, please feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: @rene voting is a valid option to complete a review, so I see that for votes to remain anonymous displaying anything else then "Reviewed" would be detrimental.

Comment: Consensus with other reviewers is a poor guideline. There are still many robo-reviewers.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Yes that sadly is the case. However I tend to sift through actions of others, and when in doubt raise it up here.

Comment: @Luuklag You can see who reviewed any skipped LA's and what action they took if you enable it in the bottom right of the review history page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's only one reviewer per review for Late Answers so there's no community concensus to see. You're the only reviewer.

The closest you'll get is checking if the flags you've raised during reviews are marked helpful or not. Your flags will feed the answer into the other review queues where it might be deleted by consensus. If that happens (and you're +10k rep so you can see deleted posts) you can visit the answer from your flagging history and verify that it was deleted during a review.

[image: Flagging history]

[image: deleted post]

Comment: Also, when you're +10k, you can see past review items done by others (e.g. [recent "late answer" reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/history), not only yourself.

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know that :)

Comment: You don't need to actually visit the answer to see that it was deleted - the flagging history itself will show that via the highlighted title.

Comment: @ekhumoro But you need to visit it to see *how* it was deleted. Although I'm pretty sure that if the OP self-deletes it will show up as disputed instead of helpful. I found a disputed LQ flag on a self-deleted answer that wasn't edited. Dunno really, mainly included that bit to demonstrate that the Late Answer queue feeds the other review queues.